# Medion Akoya notebookP6620 (MD97760)

Tags: windows-vista, reinstall

I reinstalled my laptop using the Medion recovery disc. I got windows Vista back with but not all drivers are installed yet and of my other programs have disappeared.

In the device manager and have yellow question marks beside the

- Realtek RTL8101 family PCIe fast ethernet NIC (NDis6.0)
- Network controller.
- SM Bus controller.

Can someone please help me to get my laptop back to working order, with working network and WiFi connections?